# on marker click close infobubble

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3, infobubble

I am using `Gmap3` jQuery plugin with `infobubble` plugin and php to get json reponse for adding markers.

I have added GoogleMap marker using `addMarkers` option of `Gmap3` plugin.

```
{
    action: 'addMarkers',
    markers:address_data,
    marker:
    {
        options:
        {
            draggable: false,
            icon: HOST+'img/icons/google_marker.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        },
        events:
        {
            click: function(marker, event, data)
            {
                var map = $(this).gmap3('get');

                infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                    maxWidth: 310,
                    shadowStyle: 1,
                    padding: 5,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    arrowSize: 20,
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    disableAutoPan: true,
                    hideCloseButton: false,
                    arrowPosition: 50,
                    arrowStyle: 0
                });

                if (!infoBubble.isOpen())
                {
                    infoBubble.setContent(data);
                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                    console.log('open');
                }
                else
                {
                    infoBubble.close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

All is working well on first attempt but when i click on marker then infobubble keeps popping up.

Means if i have one marker and some content to display in bubble then when i keep clicking on same marker infobubble added one on other but what i need "**I need to close old infobubble if marker clicked again or other marker is clicked** " just like normal infowindow dose.

Hope i can make clear point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `infoBubble` as a var outside the `click` handler, and instantiate it there.

Then the checks for `infoBubble.isOpen()` will be relevant.

From the code you provided, you create a new `infoBubble` on each click, hence the `infoBubble.isOpen()` check applies to that newly created object.

**How to do it**

Declare `var infobubble;` as global variable.

and inside of click event handler add below line that will do that.

```
if( infoBubble != null ) { infoBubble.close(); }
```

so code will look as below,

```
var infobubble;
//other code for getting markers and all and then `addMarkers` code
{
    action: 'addMarkers',
    markers:address_data,
    marker:
    {
        options:
        {
            draggable: false,
            icon: HOST+'img/icons/google_marker.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        },
        events:
        {
            click: function(marker, event, data)
            {
                var map = $(this).gmap3('get');

                if( infoBubble != null ) { infoBubble.close(); }

                infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                    maxWidth: 310,
                    shadowStyle: 1,
                    padding: 5,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    arrowSize: 20,
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    disableAutoPan: true,
                    hideCloseButton: false,
                    arrowPosition: 50,
                    arrowStyle: 0
                });

                infoBubble.setContent(data);
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nope its not working because everytime i click it create new instance

Comment: i have solved it and i have added how i did to your answer so other user can solve it